# How to create a raster of a canvas in windows phone 7

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, canvas, mms, raster

I am looking to find a way to create a raster image of a canvas in windows phone 7. I want to be able to either save the image or share it (MMS, email, ect). I am just starting to learn C# and about Silverlight, so this is uncharted waters for me.

Thank you,
Doc Haven

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is the best way to go about this, but this is how I have found my solution to my own problem:

One of the constructors for the `WriteableBitmap` class allows you to pass it a UIElement and a Transform such that the call `new WriteableBitmap(canvas, null);` would create a `WriteableBitmap` from the `Canvas`. I later set my `Image` source to that `WriteableBitmap`.

I do hope that this helps anyone else that may come into this issue in the future!

Thank you,
Doc Haven

Answer (score 0):

checkout the `RenderTargetBitmap` class, you can create a bitmap image of any visual element then do what you want with it.